# Get a sounds length (duration) in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, howler.js

I am using howler.js to manage sounds within my html/css/js project, everything is working fine, the only point that took me hours of research without success is: How can I get the length of a sound using howler.js methods?

Answer (score 9):

Using howler.js, you can simply do the following:

```
sound._duration
```

You may also want to wrap that inside of the onload event as you won't be able to get the duration until the sound has loaded.

Comment: Thx James, that's what i needed, however does sound._duration exist in the howler.js web page on goldfirestudios.com ? or it's something that any javascript programmer should know?

Comment: No, it isn't in the documentation because it is intended as a private variable, but that'll change in v2.0.

Comment: @JamesSimpson is there a way to get the audio duration before loading the sound? I want to show the playback length when user opens my web page. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without any library I would recomend using `.duration` property of your audio element. which returns the amount of seconds that the audio should play.